# Error with new version

Tags: python, selenium

I have Arch linux and recently it's python packages was upgraded to the 3rd branch. Now I'm not able to run selenium-python bindings. When I run it (even with old-python version) I get:

```
    from selenium import selenium
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.0a5-py2.7.egg/selenium/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from selenium.selenium import selenium
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.0a5-py2.7.egg/selenium/selenium/selenium.py", line 193
    raise Exception, result
```

What could it be? (Btw, looks like my selenium was built with 2.6 python).

---

**UPD** I tried to get selenium again but:

```
 easy_install-2.7 selenium
install_dir /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
Searching for selenium
Best match: selenium 2.0a5
Processing selenium-2.0a5-py2.7.egg
selenium 2.0a5 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.0a5-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for selenium
Finished processing dependencies for selenium
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it and it works for me. The error doesn't make sense to me since line 193 in selenium.py is part of the Selenium object "start" method - it shouldn't be called at import time.

Maybe ask the [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users)?